# Raspberry Pi Zero W -- route domain to local IP

Tags: pi-zero-w

I set up an access point using [this tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) and was wondering if I could set up something where if I connect to the access point and went to `example.com` it would route to `192.168.4.1:80` or something like this?

Comment: What is it you want to do exactly? You can set up static routes on your network in different ways (Raspberry Pi doesn't have to be involved), but I get the feeling that routing to a fixed IP is not necessarily your end game.

Comment: You can map a specific host such as example.com to an IP using /etc/hosts. Drop the ":80", however, since hosts isn't really for port mapping. https://askubuntu.com/questions/183176/what-is-the-use-of-etc-hosts

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you have to configure dnsmasq to map a domain to that IP address. Check the content of default dnsmasq config file. It has plenty of information for many different scenarios.